# jQuery Plugin: Can I get the selector that was used to select elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

If I select elements to enable jQuery plugins like

```
$(".clickaway").clickaway();
```

Can I somehow get the selector `.clickaway` that was used in the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you would have noticed it digging into the object using Firebug, but just the [.selector](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property of the jQuery object.

Comment: Note: The `.selector` property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and **removed in jQuery 1.9**.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to a similar question... https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165306/2358222  This is a solution I came up with after loads of digging around on the web and in chrome's console.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
$(".clickaway").clickaway().end()....
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually I want the selector string ".clickaway" that I can use within my plugin `(function($) { $.fn.clickaway = function() { // I want to use that string here } })(jQuery)`

Comment: sorry - misunderstood your question.  Agent_9191 seems to have nailed it :)